# ReactNative Flux TabBar Router with Status Bar Alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to use `react-native-router-flux` with `react-native-statusbar-alert`. This work's without any issues until I get to TabBar.

Consider the following code (Of mine).

```
 return (
      <View>
      <StatusBarAlert
      visible={this.state.alert.visible}
      backgroundColor={this.state.alert.backgroundColor}
      color={this.state.alert.text}
      message={this.state.alert.msg}
      />
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="loginPage" 
            component={Login} 
            title="Login"
            initial={true}
            hideNavBar={true}
            style={{top: -20}}
            hideStatusBar={this.hideStatusBar.bind(this)}
            showStatusBar={this.showStatusBar.bind(this)}
            />
            <Scene 
              key="tabbar" 
              tabs
              tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}
              tabBarSelectedItemStyle={styles.tabBarSelectedItemStyle}>
              <Scene key="tab1" component={Settings} title="Settings" hideNavBar={false} icon={TabIcon}/>
              <Scene key="tab2" component={Settings} title="Tab #2" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
              <Scene key="tab3" component={Settings} title="Tab #3" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
              <Scene key="tab4" component={Settings} title="Tab #4" hideNavBar={true} icon={TabIcon}/>
            </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
      </View>
    )
```

It's renders funny. I have tried removing the `style: -20` (required by status bar other app).

To remove the issue I have to take the `<View>` out completely and have the the `<Router>` as the top level element. This then displays the TabBar perfectly, however...

When it displays perfect like this I have nowhere to stick my `<StatusBarAlert>` as that needs to be in a `<View>`.  I could stick it in the top of each of my views, but I specifically trying hard to seperate and repeat my code (but struggling!) Very new to ReactNative, much help appreciated!

Screenshot of wrapped wrapped in `<View>` and `<SatusBar>` as first node of View.

[image: view and status]

This is just wrapped in View, no statusbar.

[image: just view]

this is just without view (works well)

[image: no view]

Comment: Can you edit your post so that it has a screenshot of how it renders?

Comment: @YoWakita - Thanks for the reply. I've edited with some screenshots now. Thank you!